# cassandra select query to select rows when atleast one column value condition is true

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a requirement where there are six amount columns. I want to run a select query that gives me rows when either one of the column value is >0 . I tried OR condition but that is not supported. Is there any other alternative? I tried selecting records checking for >0 values for each column . But this approach is a head ache if we need to check many columns.

Example records:

```
|id| col1| col2| col3| col4| col5| col6|
----------------------------------------- 
|1 | 2.0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|2 |   0 |   0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 5.0 |  66 |
|3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|4 | null| null| null| null| null| null|
```

What i need is records for id 1 2 which have atleast one column value > 0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query in Cassandra like that. To achieve such results you may need to depend on your application (like getting the row and then checking columns). If you are scanning complete database then you may use spark for faster processing.